Which Analysis to Use for 2 Likert Scale Questionnaire Groups With Multiple Responses
I have a data set that I acquired through running a questionnaire. The questionnaire consisted of participants having to rate 80 different phrases using a 5-point Likert scale; ranging from Strongly disagree to Strongly agree). I had a second group where they answered the same style of questionnaire rating 90 different phrases along the same Likert scale. Now I want to see if gender has an effect on how they rated the phrases (including both groups). Should I use a MANOVA or something like Ordinal Regression? I am a bit stumped on how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Can you explain in a bit more detail what participants rated regarding these phrases? Did they rate something like phrase fluency for each phrase and you want to look at overall gender differences in fluency ratings, and the ratings from 80 (+90) phrases can be combined to do that? Or are the 80 (+90) phrases all different from each other and you need to look at each separately?
